# Converting Geo-normalized SVG data to geojson

Tags: geojson, convert, svg

I'm working on a project for which our team geonormalized some TIFF files with [MapWarper](https://github.com/timwaters/mapwarper), then used photoshop to vectorize only the buildings within the images. We now have svg data for which we know the geo-coordinates of the bounding box (that is, the geonormalized representation of the original image corners).

My question is: Is there a way to convert an svg file for which one knows the coordinates of the bounding box to geo json? Any help others can provide on this question will be very welcome!

Comment: For others who end up in this situation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155854/matrix-transform-converting-svg-path-coordinates-to-leaflet-coordinate-system P.S. @Mapperz Why is this problem too broad? I believe the only way to solve this problem generally is via linear algebra, which makes the problem quite well defined in my book.